# Есть ли аналог атрибуту RoutePrefix в web api

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Я использую **.net framework 4.0** и **web api 1**.

Мне нужно использовать атрибут **RoutePrefix**, который есть в **web api 2**.

Есть ли аналог в первом web api?

Пример на web api 2:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/photo")]
public class PhotoController : ApiController
{
 ...
```

Comment: а чем RouteConfig не устраивает?

Comment: В первой версии Web API нет атрибутивного роутинга, то есть придется либо задавать роуты руками, либо использовать соглашения. Почитать об этом можно здесь: https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api и здесь: https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-and-action-selection. Кроме того существуют NuGet-пакеты, реализующие атрибутивный роутинг для ранних версий Web API, например этот: https://github.com/mccalltd/AttributeRouting.

Comment: Все ясно, спасибо за подробный ответ.

Comment: Вот ответ на мой вопрос(там он описан более подробно): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40671102/routeprefix-in-web-api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне нужно было просто правильно настроить WebApiConfig.cs
Вот так:

```
onfig.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "FileApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/file/{fileName}",
            defaults: new { controller = "File", fileName = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Здесь об этом более подробно: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40671102/routeprefix-in-web-api